# How to generate KML file in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, kml

I'd like to serve a dynamically generated KML file using ruby on rails. I made some research and I found [kamel](https://github.com/xaviershay/kamel) which looks great. The problem is that kame depends on ruby_kml gem which doesn't seem to be available anymore.

```
$ gem install kamel
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: kamel requires ruby_kml (~> 0.1.4)
```

Searching 'kml' on rubygems.org was unsuccessful.
So does someone know any alternative to achieve KML generation in ruby on rails?

Comment: For alternative to kamel see this answer for schleyfox/ruby_kml
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168649/ruby-kml-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KML is just another XML, you can easily make your own "writer" which parses recursively and formats whatever input is passed in as a parameter and generates a string that looks like valid KML/XML.

Recommended reading for the options and the XML layout:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: then could you guide me to do so? I'd like to make the call like myserver.com/getkml/points.kml How can I do this?

Comment: what is the issue you have ? how to define an KML or how to write it ? (do you know it's syntax?)